# Compress PNG Files Error Group in iOS

Tags: ios, png

I have made sing up, login and forget password view controller .On running this program it is giving following error .

```
 `While reading /Users/../Downloads/WowPatient/WowPatient/4-3 fam-soc history/icon@3x.png pngcrush caught libpng error:Command`
```

`/Users/../Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure`

you can download this project from this link.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j-roD0c2PyJ9n6BCxh5kZkMK_nDMhgbh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have repeated icon with same name  , so remove all repeated icon with same name or change its name

Example Check this , but there is a-lot of icon that repeated

[image]